# What to key in for my target in sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Usually when one codes for `train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3)`, `X` means the input data and `Y` means the target data, but what exactly is the meaning of target data? I've read through tutorials and I still don't get it.

For instance if I have 2 classes, both having equal numbers of features and instances, what do I apply as my target data so my classifier would do its job properly?

Comment: Your target is outcome, that you try to predict with your model. In your case I suspect it is those 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `X` contains the features of the data which are the input to the model while `y` contains the actual labels of the data meaning which class they belong to that corrosponds to the output of the model.

In supervised machine learning you have a labelled data set from which the model can learn and then can apply it to new unseen data. The training set you are talking about consists of known pairs of features `X` and labels `y`. With this data you can teach a classifier to predict which class `y'` a new data point `X'` has. This can be used for example in credit card fraud detection. Based on historic features of transactions (input features, `X`) we learn a classifier that predicts if this is a fraud (output, `y`). We can then monitor new transactions and if the model says there is a potential fraud we can act accordingly. In order to prevent the classifier from overfitting you split the data into two parts. The training part and the test part. The training part is used to actually train the classifier while the test part is used to predict how good the classifier works on prevously unseen data.